# PhpStorm debugging Magento 2 Devbox gives "Protocol mismatch" error

Tags: magento-2.1, ssh

I was able to create the dev box and start the listener script successfully, but when I start a debugging session I receive this error on any page:

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3
Protocol mismatch.
```

The main site is running at `http://127.0.0.1:32772/` and the init script is listening on port `32773`.  I receive the error when visiting `http://127.0.0.1:32773/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=14487`